# How to fix "An error occurred while processing your request" while calling an action method from a container (VS2017 / Docker)?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created an image from .net core project in vs2017 and create and run a container  from it ( via Docker).

The project works fine when I debug it from VS2017 and request for this url :

Url (debugged project) : https://localhost:44363/api/Movies/getM

which returns proper response Which I expected.

but when I call the url from started / running container it returns this error :

Url (Container) : http://localhost:8080/api/Movies/getM

[image: error]

How to solve it? any help would be appreciated .

this is the action method of getM:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Movies/getM")] // stdid,sourseid
    public dynamic getdataJoin3Table(/*int id*/)
    {
        ResponseModel _objResponseModel = new ResponseModel();

        _objResponseModel.Info = "res";
        _objResponseModel.ResponseStatus = true;
        _objResponseModel.ResponseMessage = "Data Received successfully";
        return _objResponseModel;
    }
```

docker container logs:

[image]

Comment: What is the code for `getM`? Try to run `docker logs CONTAINERNAME` to check the detail error.

Comment: the http://localhost:8080/ works fine . @TaoZhou thx for response, code just returns a filled model. I added the code to question

Comment: What is the result for `docker logs CONTAINERNAME`?

Comment: I added the log image to question

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you are trying to connect to the local database which is located on the host system. When you run your app in the docker container the `localhost` becomes the docker instance so it cannot connect to database. You can either run your database in another docker container and link them together using Docker Compose or you can set connection string as environment variable to point to the host system where your database is running.

Comment: that is correct. thx.

Comment: You could answer it So I would be able to accept the answer @AlexeyAndrushkevich

Comment: @tahaGhSa converted my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information you have provided it seems like you are trying to connect to the local database which is located on the host system. When you run it from Visual Studio it can find the local database and connect to it. But when you run your app in the docker container the localhost becomes the docker instance so it cannot connect to database anymore because it doesn't run in the same docker container.

There are numbers of approaches how to resolve this issue. First - you can run your database in another docker container and link both `app` and `db` containers together using Docker Compose. Another approach is to set the connection string to your database by setting the environment variable for your docker container. This connection string should point to host's database. Another option would be to use some external database which can be accessed from both host and docker instances.